# How to check and get newly added contact details from phone-book using react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-contacts

I have a mobile application written in React-Native and used React-native-contact from this guide: https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-contact-multi-select. And I upload these contact details into database.
Now I want to get newly added contact details from phone-book. That means if I add new contact into phonebook i want to get that contact and update my database. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Create a logic to compare the phone contact data and saved (database) phone contact data

Comment: This app use so many peoples. Then I save every contact of their contact list. because of that there are so many contacts in my database.  If there is a way to fire event when app loading to take newly added contact details it is easy to update my contact list. That;s why I'm looking for solution.

Comment: You can save a list of saved contact IDs to async storage. Then on loading you can compare existing contact IDs to that array and then fetch the diff. There is no documented way to get the new contacts from what I can tell.